# What should I write in the "National identity number" field of the Schengen visa application form?

Tags: schengen, eu, applications

What to write in the box "National identity number, where applicable" of Schengen Visa's Application Form. Is it the same as ordinary passport's serial number ?

Comment: Search for "National Identity Number + <Name of your country>" on google to find out if citizens of the country issuing your passport have any. It should *not* be the passport's serial number as it changes whenever you get a new passport. A national identity number does normally not change, otherwise it wouldn't identify *you*.

Comment: So it identifies the country, not me, yes ?

Comment: @DavidTsaturyan The national ID number identifies you as a person

Comment: No, it identifies you.  It is assigned to you by your country of citizenship.  Many countries have no such identification system, while others treat the number with such caution that they do not include it on passports.  For example, on a South African passport, there is a field called *Identity no. / No d'identité;* that's the number you should enter here if you are South African.  If your passport bears no such number, you should leave the box empty.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I think there is no such a thing in Armenian passports.

Comment: Does Armenia have an equivalent for a U.S. "[social security number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_Security_number)"?  I think that is what the form expects.

Comment: @wallyk Yes, I think it has. Surely it is what the form expects ?

Comment: @DavidTsaturyan Yes.

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53167/what-national-identification-number-to-enter-in-an-esta-application-for-a-ger